# PYTHON - test compression program two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to replace the part of my code that is commented in bold and italics but i don't know what to replace it with. I need two lists:
one that stores the words in the sentence once per unique word
another that stores the positions where the word first occurs in the sentence

This is my code at the moment:

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"

words = sentence.split()

list_of_words = [None] * 9

list_of_positions = [None] * 17

position = 1

index = 0

for word in words:
    if word not in list_of_words:
        list_of_words[index] = word
        list_of_positions[index] = position
        index = index + 1
        position = position + 1
    else:
        list_of_positions[index] = 0 ***#position of word***
        index = index + 1

print(list_of_words)

print(list_of_positions)
```

my current output is (the part that needs to be changed is in bold and italics):

```
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ***0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]***
```

My expected output is (the part that is changed is in bold and italics):

```
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ***1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
for word in words:
    if word not in list_of_words:
        list_of_words[index] = word
        list_of_positions[index] = position
        index = index + 1
        position = position + 1
    else:
        list_of_positions[index] = list_of_positions[list_of_words.index(word)]
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense! Going to try it now!

Comment: Thanks works as I wanted it! Can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: @RianLeggett Please consider accepting the answer (hitting the checkmark) if this solution worked for you.